# Is it correct to dreference a function that returns malloc'd pointer and then pass the variable addres via ampersand?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have this function here written for learning an interesting way of allocating 2D array I found out recently:

```
//############################## single array matrix
struct sam *alloc_sam (struct sam *matrix, int row, int col) {
  matrix -> single_arr_mtrx = malloc (row * col * sizeof(int) + row * sizeof(int*));
  printf ("matrix at: %p\n", (void*) (matrix -> single_arr_mtrx));
  matrix -> ptr = (int*) (matrix -> single_arr_mtrx + row);

  if (!matrix -> single_arr_mtrx) {
    printf ("can't allocate single array matrix\n");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf ("Allocated chunk of %ld bytes(single array matrix).\n", row * col * sizeof (int) + row * sizeof (int*));
  }

  matrix -> row = row;
  matrix -> col = col;

  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    matrix -> single_arr_mtrx[i] = matrix -> ptr + col * i;
    printf ("Addr %d: %p\n", i, (void*) &(matrix -> single_arr_mtrx[i]));
  }

  return matrix;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
void run_sam (void) {
  struct sam matrix;
  matrix = *alloc_sam (&matrix, ROW, COL);

  fill_sam (&matrix);
  print_sam (&matrix);

  dealloc_sam (&matrix);
}
```

Struct definition:

```
struct sam {
  int **single_arr_mtrx;
  int *ptr;
  int row;
  int col;
};
```

Is it correct to simply dereference the return value of alloc_sam function?
I run my code through valgrind and it didn't find any leaks, but still...

Also, will it be possible to use this same method of allocation with calloc function?
I find it tricky since there is two different sizeof's in the statement:
`malloc (row * col * sizeof(int) + row * sizeof(int*))`

Comment: Fyi, the `matrix` parameter is worthless. There's nothing there you couldn't achieve with a local var and a `struct sam` returned by value. Its presence does little more than obfuscate code. If `alloc_sam` was both an allocator *and* a reallocator it would make more sense. But it isn't, so it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks!
If you find anything else bad about this code - comment it please.

Comment: `row * col * sizeof(int) + row * sizeof(int*)`has at least 2 problems.  Please post definition of `struct sam`.

Comment: IMO very naive attempt. In C is hart to find a "revolutionary" method of allocating 2d arrays as everything was tried in the last 40y

Comment: Struct definition:

`struct sam {
     int **single_arr_mtrx;
     int *ptr;
     int row;
     int col;
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to allocate a block of memory that you then can use as a 2d matrix, without explicitly saying that it's two-dimensional.

If that is the case, you are passing way too much stuff to `malloc`. You want to get back a block that has enough space to hold all the members of the matrix, which are a `row * col` amount, and each is `sizeof(int)` big; so pass it just that.

```
... = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
```

Now for how you access it.
Let's say `row` is 3 and `col` is 2. You would have something like this:

[image: Drawing of a memory block]

You want to subdivide it like this:

[image: Drawing of a memory block]

It means that, starting at the beginning, for every "row" that you want to skip, you have to go up my that number times the width of a row. In the simpler case, when you have a pointer of a type that has the same size as the "matrix" elements (i.e. an `int *` that stores `int`s), the width of a row is the number of columns:

```
mtrx[2 * col] // Accessing third row (row n. 2)
```

There are cases in which that isn't true, like when you have an `unsigned char *` that actually points to larger things. `unsigned char` is 1 byte large, and so you have to explicitly multiply the number of bytes that you want to skip:

```
mtrx[2 * col * sizeof(Thing)] // Accessing third row (row n. 2)
```

The value `col * sizeof(Thing)` is usually called *pitch* or *stride*.

To you get to the actual cell that you want as you would in a one-dimensional array: by adding the column number/byte offset of that cell:

```
mtrx[2 * col + 1]
mtrx[2 * col * sizeof(Thing) + 1 * sizeof(Thing)]
```

Now, to answer your actual question: the pointer that you return from that alloc function is the exact same that you passed in. So yes, it's totally valid, but also useless. Even if you ignored the return value, the struct will still be initialized, as the function operates at the exact same memory location.

About `calloc`: yes, it's weird, I dislike it too. But it doesn't matter how many `sizeof`s you are passing, at the end they're just numbers. If you have trouble, [read the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc).

Comment: Corner cases: This answer's  `row * col * sizeof(int)` risks overflow that `calloc()` would not. `int` and `size_t` support different ranges where `int` is usually narrow than `size_t`.  `calloc()` can potentially handle total sizes even more than `size_t`.

Comment: "mtrx[2 * col + 1] mtrx[2 * col * sizeof(Thing) + 1 * sizeof(Thing)]" on one line deserves re-formatting to become clear.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in the code:

- `malloc(row * col * sizeof(int) + row * sizeof(int *));` may fail if `row * col` causes an arithmetic overflow as `row` and `col` have type `int`.  Changing the types of `row` and `col` to `size_t` is a possibility, but more generally, you should write:

  ```
  matrix->single_arr_mtrx = malloc(sizeof(int) * row * col +
                                   sizeof(int *) * row);
  ```
- the size argument is somewhat confusing as the row pointers are stored in memory before the `int` arrays. It would be more intelligible to write:

  ```
  matrix->single_arr_mtrx = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row +
                                   sizeof(int) * row * col);
  ```

  or more generic:

  ```
  matrix->single_arr_mtrx = malloc(sizeof(*matrix->single_arr_mtrx) * row +
                                   sizeof(**matrix->single_arr_mtrx) * row * col);
  ```
- this method assumes that the alignment requirement for `int` is no greater than that of `int *`, which is very likely true but was not on some ancient exotic systems such as the classic *Cray One*.
- `alloc_sam` could return an error if the allocation fails instead of always returning the matrix pointer.
- note that `matrix->ptr` is redundant as it is always the same as `matrix->single_arr_mtrx[0]` and only used in the initialization loop.  Similarly the name `single_arr_mtrx` is unnecessarily complicated, I would recommend `data` or `rowdata` instead.

The usage example is confusing: `matrix = *alloc_sam(&matrix, ROW, COL);` is especially disturbing, but since `alloc_sam` always returns its first argument, the assignment just copies `matrix` onto itself. It is useless. Just write `alloc_sam(&matrix, ROW, COL);` passing the address of the structure to initialize.

Here is an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sam {
    int rows, cols;
    int **data;
    int *ptr;
};

int alloc_sam(struct sam *matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    matrix->rows = rows;
    matrix->cols = cols;
    if (rows == 0) {  // corner case: avoid allocating 0 bytes
        matrix->data = NULL;
        matrix->ptr = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    matrix->data = malloc(sizeof(matrix->data[0]) * rows +
                          sizeof(matrix->data[0][0]) * rows * cols);
    if (matrix->data == NULL) {
        matrix->rows = 0;
        matrix->cols = 0;
        matrix->ptr = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
    int *ptr = (int *)(matrix->data + rows);
    matrix->ptr = ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++, ptr += cols) {
        matrix->data[i] = ptr;
    }
    return 0;
}

void fill_sam(struct sam *matrix) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix->rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix->cols; col++) {
            matrix->data[row][col] = value++;
        }
    }
}

void print_sam(struct sam *matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix->rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix->cols; col++) {
            printf("%d%c", matrix->data[row][col],
                   "\t\n"[col != matrix->cols - 1]);
        }
    }
}

void dealloc_sam(struct sam *matrix) {
    free(matrix->data);
    matrix->rows = 0;
    matrix->cols = 0;
    matrix->data = NULL;
    matrix->ptr = NULL;
}

void run_sam(void) {
    struct sam matrix[1];
    if (alloc_sam(matrix, ROWS, COLS)) {
        // handle allocation error
    }
    printf("matrix row pointers: %p\n", (void *)matrix->data);
    printf("matrix 2D array: %p\n", (void *)matrix->ptr);

    fill_sam(matrix);
    print_sam(matrix);
    dealloc_sam(matrix);
}
```

Comment: Changing `int` to `size_t` would probably be a good idea too.

Comment: @Moses: yes and no. `row` and `col` are unlikely to exceed the range of type `int`.

Comment: Nice.  Pedantic goals: cope with [Cray-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-1) like machines and `rows == 0` should not return -1.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: fixed for `rows * cols == 0` more useful: try and align the matrix data on larger boundaries.